# Fill outline and inline without center

Tags: mesh

I created a 2D crown outline in blender which looks like this: [image]

I want to fill the outline and "inline" in this mesh object, without filling the center: [image]

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is this a curve object or a mesh object ?

Comment: @Gorgious A curve converted to mesh

Comment: Would you like sharing your .blend file so it's easier to produce

Comment: Convert it back to a curve, go to the curve properties, set it to 2D, and set the fill mode to something other than "None" and back to a mesh :)

Comment: @Gorgious how do I set it to 2D and set the fill mode?

Comment: On the top of the curve settings, there is an option to change it to 2d @Maxisy

Comment: and then @Maxisy there is a fill mode right underneath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to break it up into multiple faces. A single 3-D face cannot really have a hole in it. I would recommend making single edge “bridges” at the marked locations.
[image: marked for edge bridges]

Answer (score 1):

Convert your object to a curve, go to the curve properties (Green triangle icon), set it to 2D, and set the fill mode to something other than "None" and convert it back to a mesh.

[image]

The geometry wil be awful though. Don't try to animate it.